# How to render Badging for Ionicons? (TabBar Icon)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `<Ionicons>` for TabBar Icon.

I'm getting data for how many notifications user didn't read yet.

`{... "unread": 1}` -> So in this case, I want to show `1` to the Icon. I guess we call it `badging`

For example,

[image]

Here is my snippet of code. If you've used Expo, there is not much changing on default project which expo provided.

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

...

tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
    <Ionicons
        name={iconName}
        size={30}
        style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
        color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
    />
```

I don't know if I can wrap Ionicons with `<View />` and do some styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using React or React-Native, you will be able to wrap your  in a  or other component. In order to get the Badging that you want, you will want to wrap your  in a  or similar component. One such can be found on npm called react-native-icon-badge https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-icon-badge

```
   <IconBadge
            MainElement={
                 <Ionicons
                    name={iconName}
                    size={30}
                    style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
                    color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : 
                           Colors.tabIconDefault}
                   />
            }
            badgeNumber={count}
        />
```